# Console returns error when I try to change the quantity of shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopping-cart

I am making a shopping cart and I'm using javascript for the remove and quantity buttons. I don't understand where I'm going wrong with the code. The tutorial says my console should return the variables priceElement and quantityElement when I log it. However, my console doesn't have anything show up when I do so. Also, when I remove an item from the cart, the console says 'dairyItemsContainer.getElementById is not a function'. I want to be able to have the total, the price and the remove buttons to be in sync when someone removes an item, for the total to be updated. Can anyone help?

Here is the html for the shopping cart:

```
<div>
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th></th> <!--- remove --->
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Brown Sugar</td>
      <td id='price'>€1.59</td>
      <td class='quantity'><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="button" id='buttonCart' class='buttonRemoved'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Soda Bread</td>
      <td id='price'>€2.99</td>
      <td class='quantity'><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="button" id='buttonCart' class='buttonRemoved'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Milk</td>
      <td id='price'>€0.99</td>
      <td class='quantity'><input class="quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td style='float: left;'><button type="button" name="button" id='buttonCart' class='buttonRemoved'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class='totalFont'>Total</td>
      <td class='total'>€5.57</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JavaScript Code:

```
var removeCartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonRemoved");
console.log(removeCartItems);
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItems.length; i++) {
  var button = removeCartItems[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    updateTotal();
  });
}

function updateTotal() {
  var dairyItemsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("dairyItems")[0];
  var cartRows = dairyItemsContainer.getElementById("dairyTotalHelp");
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRows = cartRows[i];
    var priceElement = cartRows.getElementsByClassName("price")[0];
    var quantityElement = cartRows.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0];
    console.log(priceElement, quantityElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: The function name is "getElementById" not "getElementsById"

Comment: I have changed it to element, and still the console says  dairyItemsContainer.getElementById is not a function

Comment: It needs to be `document.getElementById`

Comment: Thanks! The console doesnt return an error now when I remove it

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById()`.

This will resolve the error.